# How can I create a certain file when a particular component name is selected?

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to create, or if possible, to load a certain file, say "help.txt", when a particular component name, say "install_Linux", is selected during installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Components`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentstasksparams) optional parameter. This parameter can be used for all scripting sections except `[Types]`, `[Components]` and `[Tasks]`. The reference describes it as:

> A space separated list of component names, telling Setup to which
>   components the entry belongs. If the end user selects a component from
>   this list, the entry is processed (for example: the file is
>   installed).

So to install a file called `help.txt` into the app. folder only when the `install_Linux` component is selected you would write:

```
[Files]
Source: "help.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: install_Linux
```

Comment: OK Thanks TLama! Let me try this, then I will let you know soon!

Comment: Thanks so much TLama! It works Cool. See you next time!

Comment: You're welcome! If this post answered your question, you may consider accepting it [`this way`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179541). That's what you can do even if you answer your question by yourself and it's something that you can change whenever a better answer is posted.